# Invite Facebook friends into my app

Tags: android, facebook

I'm writing an entertainment application (a RESTful application written in Android). **I'd like to show Facebook friends and invite them into my app**. Now I loaded FB friends successfully. What will I do the next? Please give me an idea.

(I guess I should send an invitation email for them. Is it right?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My ideas:

- Call Facebook API to post your app's download link to your friends's wall.
- Send an SMS or email if you have those infomations.
- Create an app on Facebook. Then send an app request to your friends. Your friends will receive notification on Facebook. (I am currently using this to invite friend to my app)

Comment: I mean my app is written in Android. Send email then what to do? The user clicks the link, then...?

Comment: Ya you can provide link to download your app. But I recommend using my 3rd solution. That way your friends will receive notification on Facebook

Comment: And I know your app is written in Android. You can create a simple app on Facebook to send invite to your friends about your app.

Comment: People have to login to use my app. So after someone clicks the link in the notification, I'll send him to a register page (written in PHP), is it right? After he regsiters, I'll send him to Google Play and download my app. Now he can login into my app on Android.

Comment: You could send him to anywhere you want. And your idea looks fine for me

Comment: @user1417127 can you post an example of your third solution. I don;t fully understand the flow that you are suggesting.

Comment: I used Webdialog to popup facebook friends, after getting requestId String, how do I send notification to user ?

Answer (score 4):

Please take a look into the following documentation:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/

And look for Request Dialog see 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/

Those will make you're life easy you just have to select friends!

Comment: I disagree, this is  almost EXACTLY what you asked - how to connect your android app to facebook - the docs explain how to add all facebook functionality

Comment: I don't think above links are of much use, and they don't give any answer to the question.

Comment: Well I am pretty sure QVDev's answer was better. He did guide you towards the right link i.e. Facebook's sample social android app page. Here's where you should start from: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/mobile/android-tutorial/#requests_step1

Answer (score -1):

**invite facebook friend from your application or website,use this small lines of code and send invitation to all facebook friends to visit your website.i also used this script its working nicely. 
your domain must be *ssl certified* because facebook didn't allowing unsecured domains.**

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>

<script>
FB.init({
appId:'APP_ID',
cookie:true,
status:true,
xfbml:true
});

function FacebookInviteFriends()
{
FB.ui({
method: 'apprequests',
message: 'Your Message diaolog'
});
}
</script>


//HTML Code
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<a href='#' onclick="FacebookInviteFriends();"> 
Facebook Invite Friends Link
</a>
```

add this below code to your website main page..

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
if (top.location!= self.location)
{
top.location = self.location
}
</script>
```

for more detail you can check:- http://www.9lessons.info/2012/07/facebook-invite-friends-api.html